# Redis SET vs SETNX performance

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a quick question to people who are more familiar with Redis internals and perhaps know the answer.

I use socket.io and have a map of sessionID - socket(s) stored. In addition to that I use SET command to store empty value to indicate user is connected (if no sockets are associated with sessionID). To account for page reloads the DEL command is executed with a timeout. This leads to situation where I have no active sockets, but the online status is still set in Redis.

This means if user use a single tab, every page reload means the SET command is executed. What I am wondering is whether SETNX would be more performant here? Basically, would the check performed by SETNX be faster than setting the value again with SET? Assuming that the value will exist in 99.99% of cases.

My guess is that it should be faster, but perhaps there's something I don't know. So could anyone confirm my guess or explain me why SET may still be faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, `SETNX` could be slightly faster as it will not set the value sometimes. However, in your use case, the differences in performance would probably be negligible given the size of value (empty string). Test it to be certain :)

Comment: I also would add that time complexity for both are O(1) which means that performance wise they all fast. https://redis.io/commands/setex . https://redis.io/commands/set

Comment: Well, this is what I thought, I think I will move to SETNX, because the value will be set very rarely compared to amount of command executions (just like I said, 99%+ times it will not be set). But I will definitely test it, just to make sure. Thank you a lot! I will wait for a bit to see if any new answers pop up and then mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk true, but big-Oh is a measure for complexity. One command's O(1) is not necc. the same as another's, and O(N^N) could finish faster than O(1) depending on the actual computation involved.

Comment: @ItamarHaber thank you for your input. I didn't have time to test it yet, but the question was only about SETNX being faster than SET assuming the key already exists and this answers it. Answer accepted.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk one can take 10,000x longer than the other and both still be O(1).

Comment: @pzaj did you ever test it?

Comment: @OrangeDog I haven't benchmarked it if that's what you mean and used `SETNX` since the performance was acceptable and there was no need to introduce premature optimisations at that point.